# why not getting hex value and isBigNumber boolean value in timestamp?

Tags: contract-deployment, timestamp, hardhat-deploy, bignumber

Terminal when contract deployed

```
0xf33fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 has waved A message
[
  [
    '0xf33Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    'A message',
    BigNumber { value: "1665234541" },
    waver: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
    message: 'A message',
    timestamp: BigNumber { value: "1665234541" }
  ]
]
```

Here I want hex and isBigNumber value in BigNumber of timestamp but getting value as number.

Comment: How did you get that message? Javascript originally didn't have arbitrary length numbers, so many libraries in ethereum use wrappers objects like BigNumber of BN to return integers. If  you need the hexadecimal representation check the library they usually have utility functions that perform the conversion.

Comment: so bigNumber as number is common or hexadecimal value for bignumber is common ?
@Ismael